# Is there any efficient way for me to fetch only the fields filled in by the user, without me having to do infinite Ifs?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, search

I have a collection in mongodb with thousands of data in the following format (exist more 7 data):

> _id : ObjectId('63be16e7096c04c6f351c60c
>
> city: "Rio"
>
> economy: "Tourism"
>
> population: 6000000
>
> date: 2019-01-04T03:00:00.000+00:00

And I have a form with multiple fields in python (exist more 7 entries).

```
self.bt_search = Button(self.fr_body, text='Search', command=self.search_data)

self.city_entry = Entry(self.fr_body)
self.economy_entry = Entry(self.fr_body)
self.population_entry = Entry(self.fr_body)
self.data_entry = Entry(self.fr_body)
```

The user can fill in whichever fields he wants to filter the results. Ex: he can fill in only the 'city' field or fill in the 'city' and 'economy'. Or, fill in the 'date' and 'economy', among all the other possibilities.

Is there any efficient way for me to fetch the data by the typed fields, without having to fill in infinite Ifs?

I was doing it like this:

```
if self.city_entry != '':
    result = connect.db.my_colletion.find({})
            for value in values:
                if value['city'] == self.city_entry:
                    # print the values found
                   
if self.city_entry != '' and self.economy_entry != '':
    result = connect.db.my_colletion.find({})
            for value in values:
                if value['city'] == self.city_entry and value['economy'] == self.economy_entry:
                    # print the values found
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to test the filled fields. I want it to return only fields that have been filled in. I didn't finish doing the ifs, because in my original project I have another 7 fields.

I'm using python 3 and mongodb 6.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value will be `None` if not supplied, you can `$or` with `$eq` with a `null` to skip checking input for that entry. You can then chain up multiple checking with a `$and`.
Python:

```py
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              None,
              self.city_entry
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$city",
              self.city_entry
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              None,
              self.economy_entry
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$economy",
              self.economy_entry
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              None,
              self.population_entry
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$population",
              self.population_entry
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              None,
              self.date_entry
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$date",
              self.date_entry
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/epjiHPVClZc) to demo behaviour in native js syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I'm begginer to Python and I don't understand what you've done. How would the code look in python?

Comment: @f6l6p6 updated the answer to use python syntax